# Document Approval Workflow SharePoint Designer 2013 Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I've created a Document Approval Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013. It works without problems if i upload a document by myself. (I am the only person in the approval group that the approval task is assigned). But if someone else adds a document, the workflow creates the task but doesn't send the email.

Details of the error:

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. 
>   Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to http://mySite/sites/.../_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail Correlation Id: 7e73fdd4-83e1-4fda-9e23-b5c742de41c5 Instance Id: c191d66b-b8f7-4194-abcc-3f9c4fbdda09

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try to perform the e-mail notification within an impersonation step?

Comment: Do you mean an App-Step? If yes, yes i've tried this, but it doesn't work.